# Reference with content types

Tags: nodes

I want to show one content type content in another content type. Like one content type have Title, text field 1, text field 2, picture and i want to be able show in another content type. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two module you can use to accomplish your requirement (1) [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and (2) [node reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/references). Both directly added field to your content type as field which would be reference to another content type.

Select "entity reference" or "reference" in data type select of cck field.

Comment: I agree with @vgoradiya and recommend that entity reference is probably the best way forward and most future proof

Comment: I will try it. Thank you. Will i be able to get that content via client site application?

Comment: yes sure for end user, authenticated user. On client side application or web browser.